# Apache not reading or using cnf files with MariaDB (PERL)

Tags: mysql, apache, perl, mariadb, my.cnf

My OS: CentOS 7

MariaDB: 10.0.21

I have been having problem using cnf files (Though I used them before without problem on a different system). I keep getting the following type of error on my query:

```
failed: Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

here is my code snippet:

```
my $dsn = "dbi:mysql:databaseA;" . "mysql_read_default_file=/var/path/dbA.cnf;" ;

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, undef, undef, 
                    {RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0}) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

But when I don't use cnf files and put the user name in the dbh line manually, it works just fine.

My cnf file looks like this:

```
[client]
host = localhost
database = databaseA
user = MyAdmin
password = Mypassword
```

If I look at it loosely, why is apache trying to connect using its own creds instead of those given in the cnf file (which are working at command line as well)?

And yes I have tried giving the cnf file 550, 500, 600 and 650 permissions. But none worked. I'm at a impasse.

Comment: Can you edit the output of the following into your question? `ls -dl /var`, `ls -dl /var/path`, `ls -l /var/path/dbA.cnf`

Comment: Also, are you using the same version of MariaDB on the system where this works? I use the same method to connect to MariaDB 5.5.41 on CentOS 7 without issue (and it worked on MySQL 5.1 before we switched to MariaDB). Turn on [DBI tracing](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#TRACING) with the `CON` flag to trace the connection process and edit the results into your question.

Comment: You showed that it doesn't work, and you showed a workaround. I'm not sure what else you want.

Comment: @ikegami Sorry, my comment wasn't clear. The username in the config file is used *unless* the file can't be read, in which case the process owner's uid is used.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, Again, I don't know on what you are basing that, but my answer was definitely not on the right track if it's a permission issue.

Comment: @ikegami I'm basing it on testing on my own system. I'm just guessing about the permissions issue, but I'm able to reproduce the OP's issue by removing read access from the config file and disabling anonymous connections.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  a) Regarding your first TWO comments, let me get back to you on that in a few hours. b) Regarding your 3rd Comment (in answer to ikegami) I felt the same way as well.. perhaps its a permission issue, but as I mentioned, I tried changing the permissions as well, to no avail. Btw, I'm also aware that if I had given it 604 or 605 type of permission, it wouldn't have worked because of the Unix security rule that cnf files must not be readable by world.

Comment: @AhmadBilal That's why I asked you to show the output of `ls` on all of the directories in the path to `/var/path/dbA.cnf`. If the execute bit isn't set on any one of those directories, the apache user won't be able to access the file, even if the file itself has 777 permissions. Also, MySQL/MariaDB don't do anything different with world-readable files, so it doesn't matter to the database server if you set it to 600 or 644, as long as apache has read access. Obviously you should restrict the permissions as much as possible, though.

Comment: ls is working fine (sorry was away). on every step of the path. BTW permissions do matter on the file itself. 

`Note : (From dev.mysql.com)
On Unix platforms, MySQL ignores configuration files that are worldwritable. This is intentional as a security measure.`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot It seems the problem is the change in how cnf files are handled. The MariaDB 10.0.21 is equivalent to Mysql 5.6, and since 5.6, there has been a major change in how option files (cnf) are handled.[dev notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html)